# Extremely slow dnf

Tags: fedora, disk, dnf

I got a strange issue with extremely slow dnf, to the point where computer freezes for a few seconds during installation of packages. Running Fedora 29, but this is happening for years. Otherwise the computer works fine, never crashes, obviously only dnf hits some weak spot. Not only can "dnf upgrade" take an hour for 100 packages, every year when I upgrade Fedora, I wait for Christmas holidays so I can live without computer over the weekend as 3000+ package update starts on Friday evening and finishes on Sunday.

Root directory is mounted to an old SSD disk, /home on a new classic disk (WD Caviar Black), there is another disk just for backups (just to tell there are multiple disks installed). I have suspected the old SSD to misbehave, moved the root partition to one of the classic disks and it did not improve the situation (was even slower).

Journalctl or dmesg or /var/log/messages do not show anything special. Sysbench says that disk performance of every installed disk is fine, just as fine as on another (older) computer that also runs Fedora 29 and where dnf is fine (upgrade in a few minutes, annual release upgrade during lunch).

Does anyone have an idea where to look for what is happening?

P.S. 
top, iotop, iostat, dmesg, journalctl, such elementary things were checked a lot. iotop shows 99.99% activity on disk by python... (dnf) when it does the upgrade but I guess that's normal. Even sysbench (as stated above) shows the disks are a bit faster than at another computer that does dnf in a breeze.

For the make: i7-920 processor, 24 G RAM, no swap

Comment: Just to be sure: this is during the installation part, and not network?

Comment: Can you try / have you tried running dnf through strace to see if that gives any clues? Have you checked the dnf-specific log files, `/var/log/dnf*.log`? (These contain some stuff that isn't sent to the journal).

Comment: Is it cpu-bound or i/o bound?  What's the utilization of the CPU and the disks (iostat -x)?
(Long shot, but could try `rpm --rebuilddb`.)

Comment: @mattdm It's just installation, not network. Even on release upgrade, when all packages are downloaded and the computers is installing them in single user mode, it takes a long time. So network or any other software interference seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: I have tried perf as @Joe Mario suggested and **fdatasync** sems to be very slow. Any ideas on "step 2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert:
It would be interesting to know what system call is taking the longest.

Can you install a simple (random) package using perf trace and then sort to find the longest calls?

For example:
 # perf trace -s -o /tmp/trace.out dnf install -y xorg-x11-apps-7.7-20.fc28.x86_64

And then post the contents of your /tmp/trace.out file.  It's a summary file, so it shouldn't be too large, but it will help point you at what syscall(s) are taking the longest, and if they are way out of normal range.

Comment: Seems it's getting warmer. I have tried your suggestion on both "slow" and "normal" computers and it looks like **fdatasync** is the culprit.
**SLOW**
`   syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev
                               (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)
   --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------
   fdatasync             69 20651.658     0.072   299.299  6356.138     37.69%
`
**NORMAL**
   fdatasync             68   317.992     0.065     4.676    82.016     29.37%
 `

Comment: (eventually I'll get better at editing comments, have patience with a noob)

Comment: It takes **fdatasync** on average 300 ms on the slow system and less than 5 ms on the normal.

Comment: I have tried a simple fsync benchmark https://github.com/ncw/fsyncbench

Every disk on both slow & normal computers was OK, SSDs performing better (6-10 ms/fsync) and classid discs 20-40 ms/fsync. Any idea what kind of fsync should I try to find what exactly is causing such delays?

Comment: An individual fdatasync should not take anywhere that long to an SSD.  Is it worn out?  (`smartctl -a /dev/sdXYZ`)

Comment: There seems to be another difference: I have tried
`perf trace -s dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=2048 conv=fdatasync,notrunc`

on SSD and classic disks on both systems. It took about 30 seconds on any disk, but the normal computer spent 28 seconds on writes and only 2 seconds on fdatasync, while the slow compute did writes immediatelly (0.5 s) and fdatasync for 28 seconds. Root is ext4 on both and /home xfs.

Comment: @fche, what should I look after in smartctl or can I somehow upload the output?

Comment: @fche, one thing still bothers me. When I have taken the old SSD out and used a spinning disk for root partition, it did not help at all (everything was even a bit slower). There is probably something else that makes this quick write/slow fsync  difference for every disk in the computer.

Comment: Robert:   I agree with Frank (fche) above that even your SSD sync time of 6-10 ms/fsync is way too slow.    On both my laptop (with nvme) and desktop, (with ssd), when I run the fsyncbench test from the above, link, I get 1-2 usec/sync.

Comment: Robert:   One thought is for you to drop the "-s" in your perf trace.  This will enable you to see every call and how much time they took.  Then find the fdatasync that took the longest, look at the FD being used, then look back to see what the filename is for that FD.  Then look to see if there's anything unique about it.  For example, is its size much larger than it should be?  Is it located on the filesystem you expected, etc.

Comment: I have tried "strace" of the same dnf command on both computers and fdatasync of /var/lib/rpm/Name took 7 seconds on the slow computer and 0.04 s on the "normal" one. I'll definitly try to run the tests system without SSD. @Joe Mario, your suggestions have been most helpful for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was from a long time ago, but I believe the cause of this (it was for me) may be the use of SMR (Single Magnetic Resonance) drives, which have ridiculously slow write speeds. Here are some references:

- https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/04/caveat-emptor-smr-disks-are-being-submarined-into-unexpected-channels/
- https://superuser.com/questions/1691661/extreme-drops-in-hard-disk-performance

and some vendor references:

- https://blog.westerndigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/WD_SMR_SKUs_vDS.pdf
- https://www.seagate.com/ca/en/products/cmr-smr-list/